# Getting FaultException error after publishing WCF

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, azure, faultexception

I have developed WCF service for my one of the desktop application and host into Azure server with DB.

I have just connect WCF service Url on my local Desktop application.

Once i called login method from application. then no issue.

Once i called my second method then always i got FaultException error

Error is like that see the inner exception for detail error. but once i go inside then inner exception is null.

I also put `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />` into my wcf web.config

**Once i connect local WCF with live db with my desktop app then everything is work fine.**

**Once i connect Live WCF with live db with my desktop app then not working insert and update data.**

my second method having this code.

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
     public void method1(int nm_Id, string f_LoginStatus)
            {
                class1 lo_class = new class1();

                    DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    //check records exist or not
                        lo_class.dt_date = dt;
                        lo_class.dtCreatedOn = dt;
                        lo_tblAttendance.dtUpdatedOn = dt;

                        _context.tblAttendances.Add(lo_tblAttendance);

                        Save();
                    }
           }
    }

 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(InitializationFault))]
        void method1(int nm_Id, string f_LoginStatus);
     }


   [DataContract]
    public class InitializationFault
    {
        public InitializationFault(Exception exc, string msg)
        {
            Exception = exc;
            Message = msg;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Calling above method from desktop app:

```
  lo_loginServices = new MyService.Service1Client();
  try
                    {
                        lo_loginServices.method1(lo_EmpId, "In"); // getting inner exception error here
                    }
                    catch (FaultException<InitializationFault> ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("FaultException<InitializationFault>: " + ex.Detail);
                        //more
                    }
```

I've write catch section then also i can't able to see actual error.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to Include Exception Details in Fault. Setting **[IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** to **true** to enables exception information to flow to clients for debugging purposes.

Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraswadehra/archive/2011/01/07/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-while-connecting-to-a-wcf-service-from-a-client.aspx)

```
<configuration>  
<system.serviceModel>  
  <services>  
    <!-- Step 1. Add a behaviorConfiguration attribute --> 
    <service  
      name="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.SampleService"  
      behaviorConfiguration="metadataAndDebug">  
      <host>  
        <baseAddresses>  
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/SampleService" />  
        </baseAddresses>  
      </host>  
      <endpoint  
         address="mex"  
         binding="mexHttpBinding"  
         contract="IMetadataExchange"  
      />  
    </service>  
  </services>  
  <behaviors>  
    <serviceBehaviors>  
      <!-- Step 2. Add a new behavior below.-->
      <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">  
        <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>  
      <!-- Step 3. Add a <serviceDebug> element -->
    <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />  
      </behavior>  
    </serviceBehaviors>  
  </behaviors>  
</system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```